# MongoDB shell: how to search for collections which match a name or regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

when I use show collections it returns a list of all collections which is pretty long, how can I write a query to return collections matching a pattern. I was hoping for something like db.collections({name:/pattern/}) but couldn't find

Comment: When you have so many collections in your database that you need to match them with regular expressions, you might want to reconsider your database architecture. In MongoDB, fewer collections are usually better.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`db.getCollectionNames()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/) with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (collection) { return /pattern/.test(collection) })
```

Comment: This is a perfect response and should be the accepted solution.

Comment: agreed helped me with the exact question +1

Comment: What if I need to pass the pattern as a variable? For example;

    var patterns = ['pattern1', 'pattern2'];

    for(var i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (collection) {
        return /patterns[i]-/.test(collection)})
    }

This does not work !