# How can i find MongoDb collection using characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
[{
    "title": "abc",
    "limit": 1
},
{
    "title": "airline filter",
    "limit": 1
},
{
    "title": "adnjn dnjnd",
    "limit": 1
},
{
    "title": "baudur",
    "limit": 1
},
{
    "title": "admin Panel",
    "limit": 1
}]
```

In the above code i need to search based on character means if we pass "a" then it will search title have "abc","airline filter" etc..
Can anyone help me

Comment: Let us know what you have tried

Comment: I tried like this
collection.createIndex( { title: "text" },function(err,result) {
    if(err) {
      callback('unable');
    } else {
      collection.find({
             $text: {
                 $search: title,
                 $language: "en"
             }
         }).toArray().then(function(entries) {
             callback(null, entries);
         }).catch(function(err) {
             callback(new Error(err));
         });
    }
  } )

Comment: Are you looking for documents where title begins with 'a' or title contains 'a'?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wildcard text index as mentioned here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes and then use $text operator to search: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text

Comment: I think misunderstood my question.. I dont want to search in different field.I need to search in one field but it wil filter title who have "a" character like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for wild card searches in a collection, then this might help.

[mongodb wildcard search with 'like'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305561/how-to-query-mongodb-with-like)

If you are looking for any collection with a pattern, this might help.

[search for collections that match a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684307/mongodb-shell-how-to-search-for-collections-which-match-a-name-or-regex)